# how to change the energy level of nodes on cooja

Tags: contiki, energy, cooja

I use the wireless sensor network simulation software cooja I want to know how I can change the level of each node manually. Is this function (cc2420_set_txpower()) able to help me and how? if not, do you have any idea about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cc2420_set_txpower() will only change the power consumption rate of node. In cooja the nodes have infinite energy levels. What you can do is that you can run simulation for certain time and then process powertrace logs to compute total energy depleted.